# jQuery parse xml not returning data in ie

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I am parsing an xml file after a ajax call to 'get' the xml file. I am trying to return one of the nodes (using the find method). however it will not return the value in ie - fine in firefox. i am doing a alert to test the value and it just comes back blank. Below is the code:

```
function autoFeedGetter () {
 $('#notifyBox').empty();
  $.ajax ({
  type: "GET",
  url: "actual url removed",    
  datatype: "xml",
  success: checkNoteDate 
  }); 
  };
 // get time date saved to fullDateTime Variable 

 function checkNoteDate (xml) {
  var noteDate = 'Not';
  var lastSplit = 'Not'; 
  // get published date from feed
  noteDate = $(xml).find('entry published:eq(0)').text();    
  alert(noteDate);
}
```

The problem seems to be with this method - `noteDate = $(xml).find('entry published:eq(0)').text();`

however i have tried various other versions of this including:
noteDate = $(xml).find('entry:first published').text();

if any one has any info will be most appreciated.

example xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:taxo="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/taxonomy/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/" xmlns:ibmfs="http://purl.org/net/ibmfeedsvc/feedsvc/1.0" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
  <title>Notifications</title>
  <link rel="alternate" href="http://www.#.com/notifyme" />
  <subtitle>This feed has been created using ROME (Java syndication utilities)</subtitle>
  <entry>
    <title>This is another test message !</title>

    <link rel="alternate" href="http://#/cwweb/" />
    <author>
      <name>ContentWatch</name>
    </author>
    <updated>2010-02-12T14:22:19Z</updated>
    <published>2010-02-12T14:22:19Z</published>
    <dc:creator>ContentWatch</dc:creator>

    <dc:date>2010-02-12T14:22:19Z</dc:date>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <title>You got mail!</title>
    <link rel="alternate" href="http://#/cwweb/" />
    <author>
      <name>ContentWatch</name>

    </author>
    <updated>2010-02-10T12:11:49Z</updated>
    <published>2010-02-10T12:11:49Z</published>
    <dc:creator>ContentWatch</dc:creator>
    <dc:date>2010-02-10T12:11:49Z</dc:date>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

sensitive data removed - i am able to successfully parse the data in full but not retrieve one element - e.g. i am looking for the first published date

Comment: Can you give an example of the xml you are downloading?

Comment: Probably just a typo but, the `datatype` option to `.ajax()` should be `dataType`, not `datatype`.

Comment: Cheers Crescent Fresh was indeed a typo well spotted :-)

Comment: @jonnyhitek did you find out the answer of this question bcoz i am having same problem

Answer (score 0):

Looking at andrea varnier's reply at the bottom of http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/adb2b047f3761179?pli=1, it would appear that IE doesn't work with xml files loaded up from your local machine. There is also a solution postage there if you don't want to rely on it just working when you deploy your page:

```
success: function(xmlData){ 
var data; 
if ( typeof xmlData == 'string') { 
    data = new ActiveXObject( 'Microsoft.XMLDOM'); 
    data.async = false; 
    data.loadXML( xmlData); 
} else { 
    data = xmlData; 
}
```

So it looks like IE has left the XML as a single string, so that method loads it up into an xml document object. You can then use jQuery on that object.

Comment: Cheers paul i have already tried noteDate = $(xml).find('entry published:first').text() 

which is fine in firefox but returns blank in ie will try your second sugestion and let u know how i get along. cheers

Comment: I've edited the answer with a potential solution I found on Google.

Comment: cool thanks for your extra effort Paul I will give this whirl and let you know the out come :)